# Is there a reliable way to check if a trigger being fired was the result of a DML action from another *specific* trigger?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, trigger, sql-server-2019, standard-edition

Is there any way to tell from within a trigger, when it gets fired, that it is being fired as the result of a DML action that occurred within another *specific* trigger?

Any chance any information about the call stack is exposed in the [`EVENTDATA()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/triggers/use-the-eventdata-function?view=sql-server-ver16) function? Or another function? I'd prefer not having to shred XML.

I'm ideally shooting for getting the name of the original trigger that executed the DML that caused the second trigger to fire, from within the scope of that second trigger. But I'm open to similar ways of identifying the source too.

I have full control over the code of both triggers in question.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use [`TRIGGER_NESTLEVEL`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/trigger-nestlevel-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) with an objectid parameter

```
IF TRIGGER_NESTLEVEL(@@PROCID) > 0
BEGIN
    -- do stuff
END;
```

The `EVENTDATA()` function is only relevant for DDL triggers anyway.